# Aproximation of H2 combusion limits

Tags: combustion

I'm looking for a relatively simple approximation for combustibility limits of H2/O2/N2 gas mixtures over temperature/pressure. (It *doesn't* need to be conservative.)

I've found a fair bit of data for H2 mixtures at room temperature and above (rocketry in particular tends to care a fair bit about this), but very little for lower temperatures.

Squinting at figure 3 of [MODELING THE RISK OF FIRE/EXPLOSION DUE TO OXIDIZER/FUEL LEAKS IN
THE ARES I INTERSTAGE](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110004369/downloads/20110004369.pdf), for instance, gives the following approximations for H2/O2/N2 mixtures (presumably at standard pressure, though the source doesn't say):

(v/v)% O2 must be >= 7.25 - 0.00648*T_K, and
(v/v)% H2 must be >= 5.06 - 0.00667*T_K

...but this is from data in the range of 70F-900F, and as such is probably terrible at lower temperatures. Ditto, this doesn't take pressure into account at all (though from what I've seen the effects of pressure on H2 combustibility are weird. A minimum in LFL at ~0.3 bar, an intermediate maximum at ~20 bar, and then asymptotic from there.)